# Maven: how to change classes jar name in war?

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I use `archiveClasses` and `attachClasses` in settings of maven-war-plugin in order module classes to be packed in jar.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I'd like to change this .jar name. For example, war-classes.jar instead of module-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

How can I do it if I can?

Comment: The name of the jar is the maven artifactId. I don't see any reason why you would want your jar different from the name you are using for maven identification.

Comment: The main idea was to erase version from jar name namely -1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to `outputFileNameMapping` to do some filename modification (I'm not it will suit your needs).

```
<configuration>
      <outputFileNameMapping>${artifactId}.jar</outputFileNameMapping>
  ...
</configuration>
```

The pattern you specify in `outputFileNameMapping` will be the file name of the jar containing all your code of your war artifact (only there if you also use `<archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>` of course).

But additionally, this pattern will be appended to all you dependencies (with a dash as separator) so for instance `log4j-4.16.jar` will be named `log4j-myWebApp.jar` (assuming ${artifactId} is resolved to `myWebApp` and that you use this pattern `${artifactId}.jar`)

Comment: The problem of `outputFileNameMapping` that it affects all dependency  libs :( Another approach is to improve sources of maven-war-plugin, but it is not good for long-term as any update in original maven-war-plugin would lead to new sources improvement.